# How to calculate how far a user has scrolled in a TListView but not while the user is scrolling?

Tags: delphi

I have a `TListView` with some specialised areas that display tool tips.  Because I cannot by design define specific areas on a `TListView` to display more than tool tip per `Subitem`.

So I have created a structure that contains their position as will as the tool tip (hint).  This part works fine.  However, these positions are relative within the `TListView` to its top, so once the user has scrolled, the `MousePos` still refers to the complete visible of the `TListView`, regardless of where the `TListView` is scrolled to.

That makes sense; but I wish to add to the Y-coordinate how far the user has scrolled down.  (I'd also like to do the same for the X-coordinate, but that is less relevant.)  But as far as I can gather there is A) no mechanism on a `TListView` to detect this and B) most guides that talk about `TListView` and scrolling refer to capturing the scrolling *as it is happening*, and not in my case, during a different event (in this case, on mouse move).

So how would I detect or calculate how far the user has scrolled while not in a scrolling event?

Comment: Does the `TopItem` property of `TListView` help at all?

Comment: @mbratch: Well, that is certainly an interesting property.  But its `Position.Y` is its position within the table, and I don't know how to get the height of each item.

Comment: @TLama: Thank you, that worked exactly as I needed.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There's a mechanism: `ListView.ViewOrigin`.

> Read ViewOrigin to determine the logical origin of the list image.
>   When the list view is not scrolled, ViewOrigin is (0,0). Otherwise,
>   use the x coordinate to determine the number of pixels the view is
>   scrolled horizontally, and the y coordinate to determine the number of
>   pixels the view is scrolled vertically.

```
var
  Pt: TPoint;
begin
  Pt := ListView1.ViewOrigin;
```

This should only work if your listview is in `vsIcon` or `vsSmallIcon` view style. (You don't seem to have mentioned what view style you're using). Nevertheless with a simple test here, looks like it also works in `vsReport` style. ViewOrigin.Y gives exact same value of an 'nPos' of `TScrollInfo` retrieved by a`GetScrollInfo` call.